# How to retrieve values from a JSON request?

Tags: json, razor, telerik, pie-chart

So I am using Telerik to implement a chart using the following code

```html
 @(Html.Kendo().Chart<OCM.Model.Dashboard>()
                        .Name("chart")
                        .Title(title => title
                                .Text("Customer Satisfaction")
                                        .Position(ChartTitlePosition.Bottom))
                                .Legend(legend => legend
                                .Visible(false)
                        )
                        .ChartArea(chart => chart
                            .Background("transparent")
                        )
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "background: center no-repeat url(" + @Url.Content("~/Content/shared/world-map.png") })
                        .Series(series =>
                        {
                            series.Pie(new dynamic[] {
                                new {category="Happy",color="#9de219"},
                                new {category="Unhappy",color="#90cc38"},
                                new {category="Normal",color="#068c35"}
                            })
                            .Labels(labels => labels
                                .Template("#= category #: \n #= value#%")
                                .Background("transparent")
                                .Visible(true)
                            )
                            .StartAngle(150);
                        })
                        .DataSource(ds =>
                        {
                            ds.Read(read => read.Action("GetSatisfaction", "Dashboards"));
                        })
                        .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
                            .Visible(true)
                            .Format("{0}%")
                        )
                    )
```

And I am using a JSON request via a controller to get values back from the Database.

```
public ActionResult GetSatisfaction([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return Json(Data().ToDataSourceResult(request));

    }

    private List<DashboardViewModel> Data()
    {
        var details = new List<DashboardViewModel>();

        List<Dashboard> social = BALDashboard.GetSocialMediaDashboard();

        Mapper.CreateMap<Dashboard, DashboardViewModel>();

        return Mapper.Map<List<DashboardViewModel>>(social);


    }
```

Now the JSON request works and i am able to retrieve values from the Database. My problem is I want to pass these values onto the chart for Happy, Unhappy and Normal so that the pie chart values display but since I guess JSON passes it in the form of an array it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

So i resolved the issue by using ViewBag and scrapped the JSON request

```
        ViewBag.Happy = 2;
        ViewBag.UnHappy = 2;
        ViewBag.Normal = 2;
        List<Dashboard> social = BALDashboard.GetSocialMediaDashboard();

        Mapper.CreateMap<Dashboard, DashboardViewModel>();

        //if(social == null)
        //    social = new Dashboard();

        ViewData["social"] = social;

        ViewBag.Happy = social[0].Happy ;
        ViewBag.UnHappy = social[0].UnHappy;
        ViewBag.Normal = social[0].Normal;
        return View();
```